# Is it ok to use multiple session and connection on JMS (ActiveMQ)?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jms, activemq-classic

I must handle about 100 JMS Queue in a point-to-point messaging architecture. Every queue has a consumer. So I will have 100 consumer threads to handle them. Is it ok?

Answer (score 0):

1)ActiveMQ Support your request(suggest write a connection pool)
2)you should confirm you server configuration whether is ok,when
  QPS is high,

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 100 queues, you could use a single queue and provide JMS message properties, having each consumer filter just the messages it wants.

What this does is give you some more options in architecture and deployment.  You could have a single process consume multiple type of messages.  Depending on your scaling issues, you could have multiple instances of a single consumer spread out among processes/servers/whatever.

You could also have one consumer for all 100 logical queues, reading the property and figuring out where to hand off the message internally, again, depending on whatever design issues you're running into.

Overall, messaging is so light-weight that it takes a significant volume of messages or a significant size of individual messages to really hurt things.  I've got an ActiveMQ app that upon restart might have to process 10K/20K messages and it's complete in seconds.  Fairly small messages, but still very possible (and my experience with other MQs is similar performance, as long as your processing is not too overwhelmingly difficult, you should be able to keep up).

Comment: How to make one consumer for 100 queues, since one queue must have one consumer? (I don't want to use topic)

Comment: Also, my messaging system is a part of an integration system. The other side is using Node.js, and their stomp-client must receive json message. So, an JMS message is not available :(

Comment: It's possible to have one process connect to any number of queues, or as I mentioned, use a single queue and filter based on JMS properties, part depends on how the messages are defined or how different they are.  Very possible, I've done it.

Comment: The other side can just receive json message, they cannot send or read JMS properties.